# what is this "user removed" thing?

Tags: discussion, bug

From time to time I remember having seen negative-points on my sum, indicated by the phrase "user removed". Eventhough still annoying, that's not much of a problem. Nevertheless, you just wonder the reason of losing your points.

But today I saw 290 points reduced as again a mysterious user was removed. I would like to learn:

1. who is that removed user ?
2. who removes him/her and why ?
3. **why his/her upvotes are also removed** ?
4. does that also happen to other (top) members ?

I cannot recall anyone who would alone give me 290 points. I checked my answers and the top guy is (afaik) Rohit and he is not removed. In addition, my number of answers still the same, so I've not answered this guy's questions it seems. I really wonder who's that mysterious guy who upvoted me 29 times and then removed for some reason and why then upvotes are deleted too.

Once I remember, some member (systematically) upvoted me about 130-150 (not sure) points in one day and his upvotes were immediately reverted by the **system** which thinks that this is not a legit upvoting. But that's different. I know that guy, but for this you don't know who s/he is.

This **user removal** really annoyes; why the points are also removed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been discussed quite a lot elsewhere:

[link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470), 
[link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740) (and more links from there ...)

And don't you worry about 290 points, I'm the main victim :)

[image]

Comment: My bad, do not follow the meta close enough... btw: 850 points wow ! quite depressing, yet proportionally speaking I lost more ;-))

Comment: Ya, I "only" lost 310! :-)

Comment: About this particular case: [Stack Exchange Meta: Massive user removal in one night?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328642/massive-user-removal-in-one-night)